# MySQL how to add days to column

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the  my query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE product_created > NOW() ORDER BY product_created DESC
```

How can I add days to product_created?

Here's what I want to happen `product_created+5days > NOW()`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE   DATE_ADD(product_created ,INTERVAL 5 DAY) > NOW() ORDER BY product_created DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), see example below:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE DATE_ADD(product_created,INTERVAL 5 DAY)  > NOW() ORDER BY product_created DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE DATEDIFF(product_created,NOW() >= 5 ORDER BY product_created DESC
```